How to move home to other partition
I would like to move a home to other partition
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda7
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.39.3).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
The device contains 'ext4' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See 
fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.



$ sudo fdisk -l
/dev/sda7   207896576 2574026751 2366130176   1.1T Microsoft basic data


What was wrong?
Thank you

Your title & what follows do not match as I see it.  I'd move the home directory to another partition using live media, and not fdisk, as you also need to adjust your file-system table to reflect the change(s).  Your paste though shows you trying to use fdisk on a partition, where it's a tool intended to be used on partition tables (ie. devices; sda and not partition or sda7). Providing release details is almost always helpful.

Does this answer your question? How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?
